# Android 4.2 Lockscreen Widget image bitmaps won't load

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm trying to enable my widget in my app on the Android 4.2 lockscreen and it works fine, however it is unable to resolve any of the image uris. The error I get is this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tvshowfavs/cache/22kifo7sdmyet7x7kphdgch69: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:447)
    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:636)
    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:381)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at android.widget.RemoteViews$ReflectionAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1146)
    at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2304)
    at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2263)
    at android.widget.RemoteViewsAdapter$RemoteViewsFrameLayout.onRemoteViewsLoaded(RemoteViewsAdapter.java:286)
    at android.widget.RemoteViewsAdapter$RemoteViewsFrameLayoutRefSet.notifyOnRemoteViewsLoaded(RemoteViewsAdapter.java:335)
    at android.widget.RemoteViewsAdapter$4.run(RemoteViewsAdapter.java:993)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
    Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
```

Anyone have any idea why it can't open an image that is stored on the emulated storage? This image was previously downloaded and cached using the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), so it should be properly written to the storage directory. This is on a Nexus 10 that I'm receiving this exception when any of the images are attempted to be loaded. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured out the problem. I was using the RemoteView method setImageUri(), which it looks as though won't work since the different process can't access the file. The solution is to use setImageViewBitmap() and to decode the bitmap yourself, like this, for example: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Uri.parse(uri).getPath())

I find it strange that the setImageUri() works fine with launchers but not on the lockscreen, however.

Comment: It is better to use content providers with scheme content:// for sharing data via URI (and override method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#openFile(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String)). You will avoid security violations.

Answer (score 0):

Tomáš was right; using a `content:` Uri instead of a `file:` Uri fixed the problem for me.

See [this sample project demonstrating how to serve Files via a ContentProvider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files) from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6535817/57490).