# How to create a file that other applications (Polaris Office) can read only?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard, android-file, android-permissions

Here is what I'm trying to do in my app. I download files (docx, pptx, pdf, mov, etc) and store them in a `File`. After having downloaded the file, I want the user to be able to open it and read it. **I don't want the user to be able to modify the `File`** !

Here is how I have tried to achieve this.

```
            String uri =   nameFileStatic + extension;
            RestClientGetAsFile client = new RestClientGetAsFile(url, getActivity(), uri) {
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(File results) {
                    if (results != null) {
                        if (results.exists()) {
                            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(results);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(path, type); //type
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            try {
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(DescriberAttachments.this.getActivity(),
                                        "No Application Available to View file with extension " + extension, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            client.execute();
```

Basically, I download the file inside a AsyncTask instance. Then in the `onPostExecute()` method I open the file with an Intent.

Now the question is: where to store the file ? Here is what I tried:

- uri = `getDir("SLIMS", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE ).getAbsolutePath() + "/Attachments/myfile.docx"`. Before saving the file I always make sure the dir exists.

> ```
> File directoryMain = new File(getDir("SLIMS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath());
> directoryMain.mkdir();
> File directoryAttachments = new File( getDir("SLIMS",  Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath() + "/Attachments");
> directoryAttachments.mkdir();
> ```

Unfortunately, I can't open the file afterwards... I got an message error (From Polaris Office) but can't find any relevant message inside my Log.

- uri = `getFilesDir() + "/Attachments/myfile.docx".` I got the very same error as in the previous point.
- uri = `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Attachments/myfile.docx"`. This time I can open the File in Polaris Office, but I can't make the `File` read-only. I tried `myFile.setReadOnly()`, `myFile.setReadable(true)` and `myFile.setWritable(false)` but I was still able to modify the File in the end.

So I guess for now I will still store those File in the sdcard but I'm really annoyed about the write permission.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) inside your app and launch the viewer app with a reference to the content scheme, such as `content://com.mydomain.myapp/file/filename.jpg`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this and give some feedback later.

Comment: I never used Content Provider so far and it seems to be quiete complicated. Could you give me some keypoints to implement what I'm trying to do ? For example which classes should I use and which methods should I override ?

Answer (score 0):

As [323go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15973577/1685143) suggested, I implemented a ContentProvider. My code is from [CommonsWare's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6535817/1685143).

Here is my code to download the file. Once the file is downloaded, I save it as "ComingFromSLIMSDatabase" + extension. Extension can be docx, pptx, pdf, ect. Once my file is downloaded, I call start an Activity with an implicit Intent and give the uri of the content Provider.

```
String uri = nameFileStatic + extension;
            RestClientGetAsFile client = new RestClientGetAsFile(url, getActivity(), uri) {
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(File results) {
                    if (results != null) {
                        if (results.exists()) {
                            results.setReadable(true);
                            try {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(AttachmentProvider.CONTENT_URI
                                        + "ComingFromSLIMSDatabase" + extension)));
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(DescriberAttachments.this.getActivity(),
                                        "No Application Available to View file with extension " + extension, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            client.execute();
```

Then the ContentProvider catches the call and open the file I want to show.

```
public class FileProvider extends ContentProvider {
  public static final Uri CONTENT_URI=Uri.parse("content://com.commonsware.android.cp.files/");
  private static final HashMap<String, String> MIME_TYPES=new HashMap<String, String>();

  static {
    MIME_TYPES.put(".pdf", "application/pdf");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreate() {
    File f=new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "test.pdf");

    if (!f.exists()) {
      AssetManager assets=getContext().getResources().getAssets();

      try {
        copy(assets.open("test.pdf"), f);
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("FileProvider", "Exception copying from assets", e);

        return(false);
      }
    }

    return(true);
  }

  @Override
  public String getType(Uri uri) {
    String path=uri.toString();

    for (String extension : MIME_TYPES.keySet()) {
      if (path.endsWith(extension)) {
        return(MIME_TYPES.get(extension));
      }
    }

    return(null);
  }

  @Override
  public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)
    throws FileNotFoundException {
    String path = uri.getPath();
    File f=new File(getContext().getFilesDir(),path);
    if (f.exists()) {
      return(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,
                                        ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
    }

    throw new FileNotFoundException(uri.getPath());  
  }

  @Override
  public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
  }

  @Override
  public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
  }

  @Override
  public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
  }

  @Override
  public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
  }

  static private void copy(InputStream in, File dst) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(dst);
    byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while((len=in.read(buf))>0) {
      out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
  }
}
```

With this method, the user can open a file even if it was stored in Context.getFilesDir(). Now I'm still confused. Because if I open a doc file, I can still modify it and save it somewhere else. And it's not a desirable feature at the moment.

I would like to know if anyone knows **a way to view the content of the file without letting another application save it somewhere else**.

Comment: If another application not under your control can access your data, you can't prevent it from saving that data. All you can prevent it from is overwriting your file or the data in your db.

Comment: Okay. That's what I thought too. Thank you for your answer !